# Can $f(X)\times E+g(X)$ be a Gaussian if $E$ is a Gaussian for non-constant $f$ and $g$?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

It is well-known that $aE+b$ preserves the normality of $E$ when $a$ and $b$ are constants. However it is unclear whether this can happen when said constants become (possibly) dependent random variables.

So for simplicity, let $E\sim N(0,1)$ and $X$ is a continuous random variable independent of $E$, I want to know if there is some non-constant functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f(X)\times E+g(X)\sim N(0,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = \pm 1/2$, each with probability $1/2$.  Then $f(x)\cdot E \sim N(\mu=0, \sigma^2=1/4)$.  Now add $g(x) \sim N(\mu=0,\sigma^2=3/4)$, and we have the result that $f(x)\cdot E + g(x) \sim N(0,1)$.

For examples of functions, let $X \sim N(\mu=0, \sigma^2=3/4)$, $g(x) = x$, and $f(x) = 0.5\cdot \mathrm{sign}(x)$.

An alternative:  Let $x \sim \mathrm{U}(0,1)$ and $f(x) = \mathrm{floor}(x+1/2)$.  Then $f(x) \cdot E$ is a mixture of a standard Gaussian with probability $50\%$ and a point mass at zero with probability $50\%$. Now, let $g(x) = 0$ if $x > 1/2$ and $\Phi^{-1}(2x)$ (the inverse Gaussian CDF) otherwise.  The resulting expression is also distributed standard Gaussian; when $f(x)\cdot E = 0$, we are drawing from a standard Gaussian in the function $g(x)$, and when $f(x) \cdot E \sim N(0,1)$, $g(x) = 0$, so the sum is still a standard Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems like this case is due to the constraint that the distribution of $f(x)\cdot E$ is still Gaussian. I'm curious about when $f(x)\cdot E$ breaks Gaussianity, can $g(x)$ still fix that?

Comment: @Konzi - I've added such an example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your distribution is now that of two variables, $P(X,E)$, but for every value of $x$ the distribution of $E$, that is $P(E|X)$, is still Gaussian/Normal. It would be trickier, if $E$ and $X$ were correlated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there seems to be some misunderstanding. Let $C=f(X)\cdot E+g(X)$, my distribution of concern is $P(C)$, not $P(X,E)$ nor $P(E|X)$. More specifically, I'm interested about the choices of $f,g$ and $P(X)$ such that $P(C)$ is a Gaussian.

Comment: @Konzi your question lacks information about how exactly the two variables become one. Is $C$ just a function of two independent variables $X,E$? - then its probability density can be expressed in terms of $P(X,E)$, and $P(C|X)$ is still Gaussian. Or is there some kind of special rule for sampling $X$ and $E$? Formulating your question more mathematically (e.g., by writing the probability density of $C$) could clarify it, and perhaps even suggest the answer... but I suspect that clearly formulating it is precisley the problem you are facing (no offense, we've all been there.)

Comment: yes... you're right that writing the precise density function of $C$ is the problem I'm facing, since it depends on three unknown functions $p(x),f(x),g(x)$ of unknown forms. Perhaps you could shed some light on that?

Comment: Writing $p_C(c)=\int p_X(x)p_E(\frac{c-g(x)}{f(x)})dx$ doesn't seem to suggest the set of satisfying functions $p_X(x),f(x),g(x)$.

Comment: @Konzi something like $p(c)=\langle\delta(c-f(x)e-g(x))\rangle_{X,E}=\int dxde\delta(c-f(x)e-g(x))p(x)p(e)$

Answer (score 1):

Generally the answer is no, loosely understanding "non-constant" also bans trivialities involving sets of probability zero.  But when $X$ also has a standard Normal distribution and $|\rho|\lt 1,$ notice that

$$Y = \rho\operatorname{sgn}(X) E + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,X$$

also has a standard Normal distribution.  The coefficient function $f(x) = \rho\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,x$ are almost surely non-constant.

This claim can be demonstrated by noting (i) the transformation $(x,e)\to (x,\operatorname{sgn}(x)e)$ is almost surely differentiable and one-to-one; (ii) where it is differentiable, its Jacobian is $1;$ and (iii) the bivariate Normal density is unchanged by negating $e.$

BTW, an analogous construction applies to any bivariate Normal variable $(X,E)$ with zero mean.

Comment: So seems like we can further generalize the specification to $|f(x)|$ being a constant in $[0,1]$ and $g(x)\sim N(0,1-f(x)^2)$.